# How do I install ubuntu on a Asus F55A with freedos

Tags: 13.04

How do I install ubuntu on a Asus F55A with freedos. I don't have a boot CD but an USB stick, and a second notebook with ubuntu already installed. sorry for my ignorance, every help is appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at [Install Ubuntu 13.10](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest)

Answer (score 0):

- Create a bootable ubuntu usb drive using unetbootin software on the notebook.[How to install and run UNetbootin?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217981/how-to-install-and-run-unetbootin)
- Dualboot windows and ubuntu [How can I dual boot Windows and Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107538/how-do-i-set-up-a-dual-boot-windows-and-ubuntu)