# How To Install Ubuntu For "Pine 64" computer

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation

I am considering the purchase of the new "[Pine 64](http://pine64.com)" computer.

This computer uses a MicroSD memory card for the operating system.  I would be using Ubuntu for the operating system.  The notes indicate it is compatible with Ubuntu as the operating system.

The FAQ says:

'With the microSD card inserted in the card slot, all files necessary for booting should be installed in a microSD card with FAT32 partition.'

My question is if a FAT32 partition is default or will I have to do something special when I install Ubuntu on the MicroSD card?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download the latest [ARM-HF image of Ubuntu](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/releases/14.04/release/ubuntu-core-14.04-core-armhf.tar.gz)

Use unetbootin to flash the image to your SD card if you are on Linux

Use Win32DiskImager if you are on Windows

Done :)

Comment: Can I do this from within Ubuntu?

Comment: Of course! [Unetbootin is a versatile tool for writing images to devices, and it works just fine in Ubuntu!](http://askubuntu.com/questions/217981/how-to-install-and-run-unetbootin)

Comment: I want to say this back to you so I know I have it correct:  I will download the ARM-HF image.  Then I will install ' Unetbootin ' on my computer.  Then I will use ' Unetbootin ' to create the operating system.

Comment: Yes. You can find various images of Ubuntu for ARM type processors on the Web. As, AFAIK, the Pine is not out yet. I am not sure which one works best for it

Answer (score 2):

There's now better documentation. Go to http://wiki.pine64.org/index.php/Pine_A64_Software_Release#Linux_Image_Release

Download the image, and then you can flash using various tools.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/linux.md shows you how to use dd to flash.