# Iso to USB using Ubuntu

Tags: boot

I am trying to make a bootable USB that  boots Kali so I can dual boot but alongside Ubuntu. Is there any program that can do this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install and run UNetbootin?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/217981/how-to-install-and-run-unetbootin)

Comment: What does this have to do with Ubuntu Core?

Comment: To close-voters: While Kali Linux is off topic here, the creation of bootable drives with live variants of other Linux distributions and  operating systems distributions is very *on topic*.

Comment: If you have to ask, kali is probably not for you. http://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-install and http://docs.kali.org/

Answer (score 0):

For a graphical solution "Startup Disk Creator" works great, and it's not Ubuntu specific.
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu