# Can't install Unetbootin in Ubuntu 18.04 Live Boot Session

Tags: package-management, live-usb, 18.04, unetbootin, add-apt-repository

I booted my laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 (Try Ubuntu without installing method). Then, I ran the following command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gezakovacs
sudo apt install unetbootin
```

I am getting the following message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 unetbootin : Depends: gksu but it is not installable or
                       kdesudo but it is not installable
              Recommends: extlinux but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: unetbootin-translations but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I googled a bit and found that in cases like this, we should search the package name in https://packages.ubuntu.com and I did, the results are [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=unetbootin&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all) but I don't see a `Bionic` name there. Does this mean I can't install `Unetbootin` in Ubuntu 18.04? If I can, please tell me how to do it?

Comment: It seems Unetbootin is not yet tweaked to work in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Try another tool. [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) works in 18.04 LTS.

Comment: @sudodus Thanks for the recommendation! I'll checkout `mkusb` tool. But can you confirm that I won't be able to install `unetbootin` as of now in Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Yes, I get the same errors as you. Unetbootin must not depend on program packages, that are no longer available. `gksu` and `kdesudo` are deprecated and should no longer be used. I don't know about the other two packages.

Comment: @sudodus Yes, I guess that's the reason. I was just reading the `gksu` has been deprecated from Ubuntu 18.04. I'll take a look at `mkusb` now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Shubham you can try downloading the executable binary from https://unetbootin.github.io/ and can work with it.

Comment: @sudodus Could you please convert that comment to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more?  **;-)**  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Comment: @Fabby, Done :-)

Comment: Update: The commandline method (`apt install unetbootin`) is working now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Update: instructions below no longer needed

Newer versions of Unetbootin no longer require the workarounds below. Just install using the official UNetbootin PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gezakovacs/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install unetbootin
```

---

Old answer (for reference):

> ### Option 1: (Tested)
>
> You can download the last Unetbootin release from the official Github
>   repository **[Here](https://github.com/unetbootin/unetbootin/releases/)**.
>
> The last version as the time of writing is
>   [*unetbootin-linux64-661.bin*](https://github.com/unetbootin/unetbootin/releases/download/661/unetbootin-linux64-661.bin). Then head over to the terminal and
>   type:
>
> ```
> chmod +x unetbootin-linux64-661.bin
> sudo ./unetbootin-linux64-661.bin
> ```
>
> The binaries should work fine without the unmet dependencies.
>
> ### Option 2: (Tested, not recommended)
>
> You can also add *Artful* repository to your sources:
>
> ```
> cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/artful.list
> deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful main universe
> EOF Then add _unetbootin_ PPA:
>
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gezakovacs
> ```
>
> And finally update and install *unetbootin*:
>
> ```
> sudo apt update
> sudo apt install unetbootin
> ```
>
> **Note:** After installing, you'll probably want to remove *Artful* repository for security and stability reasons:
>
> ```
> sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/artful.list
> ```

Comment: Skander, Did you test that it works in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Comment: @sudodus Yes, successfully downloaded and created a SliTaz Live USB using Unetbootin on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, although I had to download _p7zip-full_ first as the program asks for it on launch

Comment: It is strange that a version uploaded a few of days ago to Launchpad does not work:  **unetbootin  661-1~bionic1 Geza Kovacs (2018-04-28)** ; See [launchpad.net/~gezakovacs/+archive/ubuntu/ppa](https://launchpad.net/~gezakovacs/+archive/ubuntu/ppa). Anyway, **I'm glad that you found a *working version* via Github**, so +1 for your answer :-)

Comment: @ whoever voted to delete my answer: I really want to know your reasons.

Answer (score 4):

It seems Unetbootin is not yet tweaked to work in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

I get the same errors as you. Unetbootin must not depend on program packages, that are no longer available. `gksu` and `kdesudo` are deprecated and should no longer be used.

Try another tool. [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) works in 18.04 LTS.

---

Edit 1:

The version uploaded a few of days ago to Launchpad does not work (today, 2018-05-01),

- unetbootin 661-1~bionic1 Geza Kovacs (2018-04-28)

See [launchpad.net/~gezakovacs/+archive/ubuntu/ppa](https://launchpad.net/~gezakovacs/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)

But @Eskander Bejaoui found a working version via Github,

- [unetbootin-linux64-661.bin](https://github.com/unetbootin/unetbootin/releases/download/661/unetbootin-linux64-661.bin)

Edit 2:

The Unetbootin PPA has been upgraded to a version, that works, also when installed via the PPA, confirmed 2018-06-26 by @Ivan Yarych.

Comment: The latest version works as of today if you run it from command line. First time it runs it shows the way you should execute it: `sudo QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1 /usr/bin/unetbootin`

Comment: @IvanYarych, Is this Unetbootin version installed via the PPA?

Comment: Yes, installed it from ppa

Answer (score 1):

The [official UNetbootin PPA](https://launchpad.net/~gezakovacs/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) now explicitly supports Ubuntu ≥ 18.04 (*Bionic Beaver*). Ergo, the [official UNetbootin installation instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217981/how-to-install-and-run-unetbootin) still apply:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gezakovacs
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unetbootin
```

**Under no circumstances should users attempt to manually inject Ubuntu 17.10 (*Artful Aardvark*) repositories into Ubuntu ≥ 18.04,** as dangerously suggested by the [currently accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1030670/415719). Likewise, there's no demonstrable need to switch to the [considerably lower-level `mkusb` utility](https://launchpad.net/~mkusb/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) (*also available only by PPA*), as suggested by [yet another answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1030661/415719).

Thanks to [owl](https://askubuntu.com/users/104442/owl) for a [surprisingly relevant ancient answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/217982/415719) inspiring the above instructions.

Comment: 181105 UNetbootin from PPA installs OK but opens to a empty window. The Windows version is good for a quick single or multi OS install but is not as sophisticated as YUMI, only having max 8GB persistence. I have rarely used UNetbootin in Ubuntu since mkusb came out. mkusb makes a great base for custom drives and works everywhere. Syslinux is just not as easy to use as grub and the UNetbootin menu is too ugly.

Comment: Ah, got it. the icon starts UNetbootin as a blank window, To get it to a usable window I got to input: sudo QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1, I like launching with an icon better.