# Renstalling Windows

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows

Using Ubuntu 18.04 trying to install install windows, I created a partition with ntfs file format (all windows prerequisites).  When booting Windows from a usb. going though the installation process is fine until it restarts which it boots back into the usb rather than the partition.  If the usb is removed to boot back into ubuntu.  How to I make the new partition boot windows first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually installing Windows after Ubuntu isn't promoted for a dual-boot system. However, since you have already installed Ubuntu on your system, take help of these two threads:

1. [Install Windows after Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)
2. [Install Windows from Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122343/install-windows-7-from-ubuntu-on-usb-drive)

Follow the steps listed in these 2 threads and you will be able to install Windows.

Update us on the progress via comments section.

Comment: Its works, I had to install ubuntu on my usb and booted to live to install grub bootloader and boot repair.  (i have to hold shift while the pc is booting to get into the bootloader) , i dont know if that should be.  ***Could i delete the partition that ubuntu is on and run windows solely?  Im not sure if it will hot it boots?

Comment: Yes, brother. Once you get Windows back on your system rename your partitions to something readable like C: - Windows; D: - Workspace etc. Once you rename all partitions, open your disk management utility using command-promt, and delete all Ubuntu partitions. 

That will actually remove Ubuntu from your system leaving Windows as the sole OS. (I did the same when I no longer required Ubuntu for my research).

Comment: Unrelated to ubuntu nw, Can you refer somewhere i see how to use cmd the make the partition one with my c drive, cuz its  not enabling me to extend the c: Drive

Comment: i tired booting ubnutu live and use gparted but its the same issue